# classpath error in java

Tags: java, classpath

I have written a java program where I am using a .jar library (Jinterface). I compile it using:

```
javac -classpath lib/OtpErlang.jar Game.java Actions.java
```

where the lib dir is inside my project folder.

There is no error when compiling but I get a runtime error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ericsson/otp/erlang/OtpErlangObject
at Game.main(Game.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ericsson.otp.erlang.OtpErlangObject
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 1 more
```

And I think that it has to do with the classpath, what is wrong?

Here is the Game class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Actions server = new Actions();

        server.moveRight();


    }

}
```

Comment: how do you run the application?

Comment: You also need to include the JAR in the classpath when you _run_ the application.

Comment: oh! I just run it like: java Game

Comment: The JRE uses dynamic linking between classes so OptErlang.jar needs to be on the classpath at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command did the trick:

```
java -classpath lib/OtpErlang.jar:.  Game
```

I have missed the :. (which tells where my main class is, I suppose...)

Answer (score 0):

Try running it like this, from the root of all your java packages:

```
java -classpath lib/OtpErlang.jar Game
```

Comment: Then I just get an error saying that the main class Game could not be loaded... why is that?

Comment: i'v updated the answer. Try going to the root package, and from there running the command above by replacing your.game.package by the package of the game class. otherwise post the Game class and the directory structure

Comment: I have not defined any package for the Game class, this class is just in the root directory. What should I write then?

Comment: I did that, still the same error :/ I will update my post with the Game class.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this.I hope this will help.....

```
javac -cp . lib/OtpErlang.jar Game.java Actions.java
```